# Does a sprinkler system by a house attract termites?

Tags: pests, sprinkler-system

Does a sprinkler system by the foundation of a house attract subterranean termites up into the house?

I heard subterranean termites (at least in the desert) come out of the ground at night to seek water. Does that mean I should set the sprinkler system to run at sundown, so they don't have to come up for water? Would that keep the termites underground?